# Define a region in python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

So my goal is to have a function happen when I click within a certain region on the turtle screen. 
So when my turtle draws a square and I click within the square, I need to have something happen.

Example:

```
turtle.onscreenclick(turtle.goto)

for i in range(4):
      turtle.forward(30)
      turtle.left(90)

if turtle.position() == (within square region):
      Activate function()
```

Comment: Kind of depends on how your square region is defined, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to figure out the extent of the region defined by the square so you can compare mouse-click positions to it later and see if they're inside it or not. Here's a complete program that first allows the lower-left corner of the square to be defined by a click, draws it, and then calls a specified function every time the mouse is clicked inside the rectangular area.

```
import turtle

def draw_square(x, y):
    global target_region

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.setheading(0)
    turtle.pendown()
    square = []
    for i in range(4):
        square.append(turtle.pos())  # Save turtle coords
        turtle.forward(30)
        turtle.left(90)

    # Find min and max coordinates of region
    min_x = min(square, key=lambda p: p[0])[0]
    min_y = min(square, key=lambda p: p[1])[1]
    max_x = max(square, key=lambda p: p[0])[0]
    max_y = max(square, key=lambda p: p[1])[1]
    target_region = [min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y]

    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.onscreenclick(check_click)  # Switch to next event handler

def check_click(x, y):
    if (target_region[0] <= x <= target_region[2] and
        target_region[1] <= y <= target_region[3]):  # Within square region?
        within_square_region_function()  # Call activate function

def within_square_region_function():
    print('clicked in square')

turtle.onscreenclick(draw_square)  # Set initial event handler
turtle.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean allowing `goto` inside the square only:

```
import turtle

def goto_inside(x, y):
    if 0 <= x <= 30 and 0 <= y <= 30:
        turtle.goto(x, y)

turtle.onscreenclick(goto_inside)

# draw a square 30x30
for i in range(4):
    turtle.forward(30)
    turtle.left(90)

# turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: I guess I phrased my question wrong. When you click inside the square the turtle has to use its stamp function on clicked location. But only inside the square, which is my problem. Nothing happens when clicked outside.